# python 3 np.savetxt(name_s,I_z) produces IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am using Spyder3.1.4 with Python 3.6.0 | Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit) | and IPython 6.0.0.

My script is rather long and calculates a series of molecular indices using the same formula and a series of different coefficients.  The script uses the `np.savetxt()` quite a few times, but one use generates the title error. The offending line is `np.savetxt(name_s,I_z)` where `I_z` is a single number of type `float64` with a size of 1.

If I comment out the line containing the `np.savetxt` statement the script runs to completion and `np.savetxt(name_s,I_oe)` where `I_oe` is a `float64` number except it has a size of (1,).

Now, it would seems to me that the different size of the name in the `np.savetxt` statement causes the error, but how do I correct it? Google has not resulted in a solution.

Here is an abbreviated copy of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Apr  8 15:17:07 2017

@author: comp

Copyright (c) 2017 Stephen P. Molnar, Ph.D.  All rights reserved.

"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


start=1
finish=31
points=300

s = np.linspace(start, finish, points)
np.savetxt('s',s)

name = input("Enter Molecule ID: ")

name_in = name+'.dat'

dtype = [('NO', int), ('LB', 'S2'), ('ZA', float), ('FRAG', int),
         ('MASS', float), ('X', float), ('Y', float), ('Z', float)]
data = np.genfromtxt(name_in, dtype=dtype, skip_header=3)

N =  data.shape[0]  
a = np.array([data['X'], data['Y'], data['Z']])
anrows, ancols = np.shape(a)
a_new = a.reshape(anrows, 1, ancols)

diff = a_new - a

D = (diff ** 2).sum(2)
D = np.sqrt(D)
r = D

def eq7(a, s, Z):
    """
    Computes equation 7 in Molnar & King (2001)
    """
    N = r.shape[0]
    I = np.zeros(s.shape)
    for i in range(1, N):
        for j in range(i):
            I += Z[i] * Z[j] * np.sin(s * r[i, j])/(s * r[i, j])

    return I

I = eq7(r, s, data['ZA'])

name_s = name+'-Iz'
np.savetxt(name_s,I)

I_sq = []
I_sq = I**2
Area = []

name_s = name+'-Iz'

Area = np.trapz(I_sq,x=None,dx=0.01,axis=-1)
I_z = np.sqrt(Area)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(s.T, I)
fig.gca().set_xlabel("Distance (Å)")
plt.ylabel('Atomic Number Transform (FT$_z$)')
plt.show()
print('FTz: ',I_z)
name_s = name+'-FTz'
print(name_s)
np.savetxt(name_s,I_z)
```

And here is the input file:

```
CARTESIAN COORDINATES (A.U.)
----------------------------
  NO LB      ZA    FRAG     MASS         X           Y           Z
   0 C     6.0000    0    12.011    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
   1 H     1.0000    0     1.008    2.059801    0.000000    0.000000
   2 Br   35.0000    0    79.900   -1.203126    3.402953    0.000000
   3 Cl   17.0000    0    35.453   -1.108639   -1.567853    2.715601
   4 F     9.0000    0    18.998   -0.938564   -1.327330   -2.299003
```

line 76 in test.py is causing the problem.

Problem solved:

np.savetxt(name_s,I_z) should be:  np.savetxt(name_s,[I_z])

Comment: Can you try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your problem, please? (It should have a variable that is the same (type / form) that the one which causes the error, as well as the numpy.savetxt)

Comment: @Steve If you have solved your own question, you have two options: (A) Delete the question, if you think it is not useful for others, or (B) Answer your own question and later accept the answer, such that it will not stay unsolved forever.

Comment: This problem has been solved.  I shall attempt to be more careful to follow up on my questions when the problem has been solved.